# Is that possible to add two different default gateways into the routing table for two different NICs in android?

Tags: android, routes, iptables, gateway, nic

By default, the packets of default connection will use eth0 to go out/in.
The default gateway in the routing table is eth0's gw ip.

When another interface said eth1 is up, I want to add another default gateway for eth1.
Is that possible in android?
Since I cannot add another default gateway for eth1 because there already exists eth0's.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A default gateway is only one, it's the default. You can have several interfaces each one with a different gateway, but only one default (your system cannot choose).

Imagine this:

```
eth0 - IP: 192.168.0.10/24 Gateway: 192.168.0.1
eth1 - IP: 192.168.1.10/24
```

You should have at least 3 routes (usually automatic):

```
To go to some IP on 192.168.0.0, go thru eth0.
To go to some IP on 192.168.1.0, to thru eth1.
To go to anywhere else, go thru 192.168.0.1.
```

So you see, you don't need more than one default gateway. What you might want is a gateway for a specific route. Imagine that you have the network `192.168.2.0` that can only be reached by using gateway at `192.168.1.1`. With the above configuration, your machine would try to use the default gateway `192.168.0.1`. You could use something like:

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

This way you'll have a 2 gateways, but only 1 is the default. This second one is only used for 192.168.2.0 network.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible in a Windows 10 machine, the second is handled as a software interface and is used for fallback. I expected android to have this feature too but  instead I have to change it manually every time my cable dies to change to ADSL.